# Behaviour of sine sums

Tags: trigonometry, summation, intuition

I was considering the following function
$$f_a(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\sin^2(an)$$
and, as expected, $f_a(x)\approx x/2$ for every $a$ (except $2\pi$ and similar). This is because the function $\sin^2(ax)$ is "on average" equal to $1/2$. That is: we are adding $x$ numbers all close to $1/2$, and if one of them is bigger (than $1/2$) then not much later we are going to find another that is smaller (than $1/2$), cancelling the effect. At first I thought that the behaviour of $f_a$ would depend on how good of an approximation is $a$ to a rational multiple of $\pi$ (problems of convergence and similar always take this into consideration), but it is not the case.

The problem begins when one considers (I found this before the $f_a$) the functions
$$g_a(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\sin(an)$$
I'm puzzled by these: they are (almost always) approximately equal to $A\sin^2\left(Bx\right)$, where $A$ and $B$ are, I think, constants (or almost constant) which depend on $a$. First of all, why does this happen? If $\sin^2(ax)$ is, on average equal to $1/2$, then $\sin(an)$ is equal to $0$ on average, so we should oberve $g_a\approx0$ always. Instead, $g_a$ is either positive (and oscillating) or negative (also oscillating), except for very few values where it becomes negative (psitive) but very small. So they are, in a sense, "very positive" or "very negative". Either way, very not zero.

Maybe it has to do with the fact that
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\sin^2(at)\,dt$$
converges to $1/2$ but oscillating and
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\sin(at)\,dt$$
converges to $0$ but is always postivie or negative so that, while it is $0$ on average, it is more positive somehow. Can you expalin this phenomenon?

Also, this is not the whole story: there are some values of $a$ (for example $a=2.8$) for which $g_a$ is "made" of two sine waves (like a standing wave), but this time the "very positive or very negative" doesn't show up. For some other values ($a=23$), $g_a$ is made up of three sine waves. I suspect this can be explained with the rational approximation thing.

Note: (you may want to graph $g_a$ times a big constant like 10 and zoom out to see the various sine waves)

Thanks!!

**Edit:** We have the following identity:
$$\sin(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi+\alpha)+\sin(\varphi+2\alpha)+\dots+\sin(\varphi+n\alpha)=$$
$$=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{(n+1)\alpha}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\alpha}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}$$
So making $\varphi=0$ and $\alpha=a$ we have a precise expression
$$g_a(x)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{(\lfloor x\rfloor+1) a}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor a}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}$$

Which looks similar enough to $A\sin^2(Bx)$.

This does not solve the "$\sin$'s average is $0$ so $g_a$ should be $0$". Also, and I find this very curious, if we substitute $\lfloor x\rfloor$ for $x$ in the formula we get a completely different function, and the "made up of various sine waves for some choices of $a$" is far from clear from the formula.

I'm guessing its a "how synched" the two waves in the numerator are: if they are very very similar then their product is very similar to $\sin^2$. This explains the "very positive" or "very negative", but no more, because the periods are $a/2$ for both waves.

Another observation: if we use $\cos$ instead, the opposite phenomenon occurs. For most values of $a$, the sum is "made up" of various waves

Comment: A puzzle in your two sums is that $n$ does not seem to be used.  Do you have a mistype?

Comment: @badjohn yes. totally a mistake

Comment: How are you getting your results?  Computer simulation I guess.  Up to what values of $x$?  Something to consider are artefacts from the floating point representation.

Comment: @badjohn graphing in desmos. $x$ as big as you want there. The observations I made are clear from the graph, and some are explained from the closed form of $g_a$. That's why I think there is nothing to do with floating point representation

Comment: You have considered the floating point issue which is good.  We have seen some previous cases where people have seen odd patterns in simulations which were entirely an artefact of the floating point variables that they used.  Most real numbers are irrational but no floating point value is.  With true real values, the values $an \mod 2 \pi$ would be dense in $(0, 2 \pi)$ but a computer simulation won't achieve this so the values of $\sin$ might not cancel.

Answer (score 1):

The function has a closed form, found with a sum formula similar to the sine-sum formula you cite $$\sum_{n=0}^k\cos(k \varphi) = \frac{\sin(k\varphi/2)\sin((k+1)\varphi/2)}{\sin(\varphi/2)}$$
thus
$$
f_a(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\sin^2(2an) = \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\frac12 - \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\frac12 \cos(2an)=\\$$ $$ = \frac{1+\lfloor x \rfloor}2 - \frac{\sin(\lfloor x \rfloor a)\sin\left((\lfloor x \rfloor + 1)a\right)}{\sin(a)}
$$
which indeed satisfies $$
f_a(x) = \frac x 2 + O(1)
$$